# Python: Should I use shutil or subprocess to manipulate files and directories as a better approach?

Tags: linux, python-2.7, subprocess, shutil

I'm a beginner in Python with a shell scripting background. I have learned `shutil` and `subprocess` modules to create files/directories.

My question is, which one is better and which of them is recommended to be used for managing files in my OS (Linux/Windows)? I've read some Python books that discourage using OS commands for these purposes.

I'm comfortable with Linux and mostly work in Linux environments, I have a very high tendency to use `rm`, `mkdir`, `cp` commands to manage files. Are there any problems/benefits of using one over the other?

Comment: You should use `shutil` (and brother wrappers around the actual syscalls) to handle stuffs natively in Python. If you don't find anything useful in Python that some command in GNU/Linux provides, go for `subprocess`.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to complement this after I go home, but just to begin I'll tell an example code I had wrote yesterday.

You can try it yourself though.

1. I had made 100k copies from an empty file with shutil and with subprocess.call, using the command time to get the execution time.
   The result was worse than I expected.
   shutil has taken 7 seconds.
   subprocess has taken 2 minutes and 30 seconds.
2. Depending on how you use subprocess, you can allow code injection... by configuration files or user input.
3. Compatibility issues. Shutil already handle it for you.

Comment: Forgetting to add to this is so like what happens to me on a regular basis. :P

Answer (score 1):

Both of them have different purposes.

The [`shutil` (Python 2)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html) module offers a number of high-level operations on files and collections of files. In particular, functions are provided which support file copying and removal. For operations on individual files, see also the `os` module.

The [`subprocess` (Python 2)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module allows you to spawn new processes, connect to their input/output/error pipes, and obtain their return codes. This module intends to replace several older modules and functions:

if you are a beginner and have worked in a Linux environment, `subprocess` can be the ideal module for you.

Basically you can execute all of your Linux commands with the help of `subprocess` functions, e.g.

```
subprocess.call
subprocess.check_call
subprocess.check_output
```

For more control you can use `subprocess.Popen`.

Let's take an example you want to execute command **"ls -l"**:

```
from subprocess import Popen
import shlex

command="ls -l"
args = shlex.split(command) #it will break the command in list acceptable by Popen
p1=Popen(args)
```

by this way you can run any complex commands.

I will recommend `subprocess` by my experience on this, it's easy, can perform a variety of tasks, can run Linux commands (basically any valid commands depending on OS), helpful on Windows system as well.

Answer (score 0):

A very important thing about shutil is its **cross-platformness** in the copy/archive operations it does. E.g., you just ask it to copy a file, you don't care if it runs on a Linux or on a Windows or on a MacOS. You just ask shutil what you want and shutil will take care of turning your requests to the suitable commands based on the host operating system.

Also as a general rule, every time a library is made for a set of *more-specific* tasks, you can expect better **performance** from it in those tasks. The docstring of the shutil gives this summary: "Utility functions for copying and archiving files and directory trees", so it's quite specific. A noticeable point is, every time you run something with subprocess, it creates a new process, so if you're doing it a lot, it might become a significant slowdown, shutil however, can accomplish its specific tasks "directly" and [without](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79890/316753) the overhead of creating new processes.